# Correct usage of Mysql real escape strings

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-injection, mysql-real-escape-string

I am new to SQL injection and would like to know if I am using the mysql_real_escape_string properly? Should I make strings for the database and password to make this secure? Any advice would be great and highly appreciated!

```
    <html>
    <body>

<img src="searchlogo.png" style="PADDING-TOP: 50px">
    <form action='./search.php' method='get' >
<label>Search Our Archives</label>
<input type="text" name="k" size="50" value='<?php echo $_GET['k'];?>'/ >
<button type="submit">Search</button>

   </form>
   <hr/>
    <?php
    $k = $_GET['k'];
    $terms = explode(" ", $k);
    $query ="SELECT * FROM search WHERE ";

    foreach ($terms as $each){
        $i++;

        if ($i == 1)
            $query .= "keywords LIKE'%$each%'";
        else
            $query .= "OR keywords LIKE'%$each%'";
    }

   $db = mysql_connect("**host***","***database***","***password***",
        mysql_real_escape_string($user),
        mysql_real_escape_string($password));
    if (!$db) {
    die("Database connection failed: " . mysql_error());
   }


     $db_select = mysql_select_db("***database***",$db);
     if (!$db_select) {
    die("Database selection also failed: " . mysql_error());
    }


   $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM search", $db);
   if (!$result) {
   die("Database query failed: " . mysql_error());
   }


   while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $id = $row['id'];
            $title = $row['title'];
            $description = $row['description'];
            $keywords = $row['keywords'];
            $link = $row['link'];

            echo "<h2><a href='$link'>$title</a></h2>$description<br /><br      />";
        }


    mysql_close($db);


    $query = mysql_query($query);
    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
    if ($numrows >0){


    }

    else    
        echo "No results found for \"<b>$k</b>\"";
     ?>

     </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string` should be used for all text values, which goes to sql queries, don't use it for username/password - as they are not part of sql query

Comment: So I would use it in this example for terms, keywords, db and each? @Lashane

Comment: quick check for your script - enter single quote `'` as your search query and enable error logging

Comment: stop using deprecated `mysql_*` functions completely! Start using `pdo` or `mysqli`! Those have better **powers** to handel sql injection.

Comment: in your example you should use it only for `$each` variable, but operator `like` has 2 additional special symbols (`%` and `_`) which are not escaped by mysql_real_escape_string

Comment: Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. You've missed escaping the contents of `$each` before that's included in the SQL text, here:

```
    $query .= "keywords LIKE'%$each%'";
```

Our preference would be to avoid using the deprecated `mysql_` functions, and use PDO or mysqli interfaces. And we'd prefer to use prepared statements with bind placeholders. They really aren't that hard.

If I was going to "escape" potentially unsafe values included in the SQL text, I'd first break up that assignment, to look like this.

```
  $query .= "keywords LIKE '%" . $each . "%'";
```

Now, we can "wrap" that variable reference in a function call, something like this:

```
  $query .= "keywords LIKE '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($each) . "%'";
```

You'd need to repeat that pattern wherever you are including potentially unsafe values as part of the SQL text.

And it's not necessary to wrap `$username` and `$password` in the connection arguments. That's not a SQL statement. What needs to be "escaped" are values that are included in the text of a SQL statement.

---

Again, our preference would be to use either PDO or mysqli, and use a prepared statement with bind placeholders. For example:

```
  $query .= " keywords LIKE CONCAT('%', ? , '%')";
```

---

Also, the values you are including in the HTML could include some potentially dangerous content. It's a good practice to run that through proper escaping. In some cases http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php is sufficient.

---

As an aside, when dynamically appending to a string containing SQL text, my preference is to include the required separator space at the *beginning* of what I'm adding, rather than having to remember to include an extra space at the end of the string I'm appending to. That's just a personal preference.

Comment: Thank you @spencer7593! I learned about this project using mysql, but will use mysqli functions on my future projects. I appreciate your help!

Comment: The other literal parts of your SQL text, for example  `FROM my_table WHERE mycol` do not need to be escaped, because those are *literal* values. It's the variables that you include... `$each` that can include "dangerous" characters, e,g **`$each = "' OR 1=1 --`** If you don't understand the classic [https://xkcd.com/327/] it's explained here [https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/Little_Bobby_Tables]. A fuller cheat sheet for SQL Injection is available from the OWASP project [https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection].

Comment: And PDO and mysqli interfaces are not a panacea to SQL Injection; it's entirely possible to write code that is vulnerable using those interfaces. But those interfaces do support *prepared statements* with *bind placeholders*. And using that pattern, we don't need to muck with calling real_escape_string functions because we're not putting variables into the text of the SQL.